# How to read before/after values of a firestore document update in a Cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This google cloud function (Node.js 12) is triggered on update of a Firestore document.

However it throws an error message on execution:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at exports.ChangeHandlerFn

I am trying to retrieve before and after value of the updated document.

```
/**
 * Nodejs function triggered by a change to a Firestore document.
*/
exports.ChangeHandlerFn = (event, context) => {
  
  const resource = context.resource;
  // log the full event object - this logs correctly.
  console.log("JSON.stringify(event): " + JSON.stringify(event));

 // The following line throws error 
  const beforeValue = event.before.data();
  const afterValue = event.after.data();

 //This doesn't work either - using val()
 // const beforeValue = event.before.val();
 // const afterValue = event.after.val();

};
```

How can i get before and after values of document update?

The code is deployed via:
Google Cloud Console UI > Cloud Functions.

**Trigger definition** (in Google Cloud Console):
Cloud Firestore BETA
Event type: update
Document path: vehicles/{owner}

**Firestore details**
Firestore data structure:

```
vehicles(collection) > abc@email.com (document) > COLOR_1 (field)

                     > def@email.com (document) > COLOR_1 (field)
```

When the COLOR_1 field value for abc@email.com(document) is changed from 1 to 0
The output of this statement:
console.log("JSON.stringify(event): " + JSON.stringify(event)); 
is as follows:

````
{
   "oldValue":{
      "createTime":"2020-09-28T13:29:41.306218Z",
      "fields":{
         "COLOR_1":{
            "integerValue":"1"
         }
      },
      "name":"projects/vehicles-990a1/databases/(default)/documents/vehicles/abc@email.com",
      "updateTime":"2020-10-01T06:51:50.092527Z"
   },
   "updateMask":{
      "fieldPaths":[
         "COLOR_1"
      ]
   },
   "value":{
      "createTime":"2020-09-28T13:29:41.306218Z",
      "fields":{
         "COLOR_1":{
            "integerValue":"0"
         }
      },
      "name":"projects/vehicles-990a1/databases/(default)/documents/vehicles/abc@email.com",
      "updateTime":"2020-10-01T06:51:50.092527Z"
   }
}```
````

Comment: At first glance it looks like your code is also being triggered when a document is created/deleted. Can you show the Cloud Functions trigger you use?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the command you used to deploy this function.

Comment: Added additional information about deployment and trigger definition to the question. Have tested this with update operation on document - the function triggers and throws error as mentioned. JSON String of event object does give us the old(before) / new(after) values as you can see, however not sure why the event.before.data() or event.after.data() does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing a function using the Google Cloud tools (not Firebase tools), then you should observe the event object structure in the Google Cloud [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#event_structure) (not the Firebase documentation):

```
{
    "oldValue": { // Update and Delete operations only
        A Document object containing a pre-operation document snapshot
    },
    "updateMask": { // Update operations only
        A DocumentMask object that lists changed fields.
    },
    "value": {
        // A Document object containing a post-operation document snapshot
    }
}
```

Instead of `event.before` and `event.after` (which are Firebase names), you should use `event.oldValue` and `event.value`.

The objects there probably also do not have a `data()` method (which is, again, a Firebase thing).  The Google Cloud docs say:

> Each Document object contains one or more Value objects. See the [Value documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/Value) for type references. This is especially useful if you're using a typed language (like Go) to write your functions.

Comment: Thanks that helped. This works: `event.value.name`   
`event.oldValue.fields.COLOR_1.integerValue`